# CakePHP Auth->identify() returning false

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm playing around with CakePHP and can't seem to get the login working. It seems that $this->Auth->identify() is constantly returning false and not allowing me to login.

I've read all previous posts regarding my issue, however, none have provided me with a solution. The users I am trying to log in as have all been created using the cake password hasher, which I have checked have been stored in the database. I have checked the password field length in the database, which is set to varchar (255), I've checked the Auth => authenticate => Form => fields are set to the correct values (the login.ctp fields are also correct). I also tried changing the $this->Form->control() to $this->Form->input() as someone suggested, with no luck.

AppController:

```php
 $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'classes'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ]
  ]);
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'password'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'loginAction' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ]
        ]);
```

login() function in UsersController:

```php
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            pj($user);
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

login.ctp:

```php
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your username and password') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('email') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

EDIT: I forgot to add that I can successfully add users, I just can't log them in.

Comment: Debug the sourcecode to figure out where exactly the authentication flow bails out, that should give you an idea what might be the problem.

Comment: what is the length of your `PASSWORD` column in the database?

Comment: @Oerd my password field length is 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the AuthComponent twice in AppController. The second load with the config for form fields is not loaded.

Load the component one time with the wanted config.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'classes'
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'index'
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I agree with your observation, but suspect it will not completely answer the question: when loading an already loaded component we get a `RuntimeException` https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Core/ObjectRegistry.php#L119

Comment: I did a "test" from on own app. RuntimeException was not thrown (haven't digged into why or if it should). And it confirms that the config in the second load was not added. It explains at least one reason why `identify()` always return false.

Comment: Cool! I was suspecting some cutting off of characters if password column is too small (cake3 switched to bcrypt)

Comment: Okay, so I've done some fiddling and discovered it works if I take out the if($user) check. Not sure why or whether this is safe practice, but it allows me to log in and out now.

Comment: @DivineMeliodas Don't do that. With that setup you can as well log in with `some.random@email.com` and pw `iloveit`. You are actually not identifying the user. Regardless the email and pw combination, a "false" user is set.

Comment: @DivineMeliodas Did you at least fix the issue mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @Christian I did and it appears to have fixed my issue